Origin of this equation attributed to Einstein
I came across this image of an equation that is apparently attributable to Einstein (his field equations). Does someone know where I can find the original equation? I'd like to dig a bit more into what the terms mean and a higher resolution image (and possibly some context on what the terms mean) would be helpful.


"I came across this image of an equation that is apparently attributable to Einstein" -> where?

Looks like someone tried (in vain) to write out a full Ricci tensor component, without summation notation. From the variables and some elements it looks like it’s in spherical coordinates. You can read more about that on the wiki; regrettably, equation identification isn’t on topic on this Stack as far as I can tell.

I found the source: the picture is referred to as "the Ricci tensor for a general case of a 2-dimensional space with axial symmetry" and it's from Larry Smarr, Univ. of Illinois https://courses.washington.edu/bbbteach/311/2007/Lecture15.pdf This is definitely not something written by Einstein.

You can try History of Science SE: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ but you still need to provide a source.

See page 13 of this pdf. It is the first part of the Ricci tensor for a general case of a 2-dimensional space with axial symmetry. It is credited to Larry Smarr, Univ. of Illinois so it was not written by Einstein.

@Quillo two Google image searches 18 seconds apart :-)

The image was taken from this pdf (thanks to comments). The original publication is:

David Bernstein, David Hobill, Edward Seidel, Larry Smarr, and John Towns, "Numerically generated axisymmetric black hole spacetimes: Numerical methods and code tests" Physical Review D 50.8 (1994): 5000. doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.50.5000

Nothing to do with Einstien.

Looks like they never got to expanding out and solving the equation in the paper.

well, it's tangentially related to Einstein since it's a GR calculation, but yes, he most definetely did not write this equation.
